# What is a sentence fragment?

Tags: grammaticality

"All of them, that is, but Storm."

Is the above line a sentence fragment, and if so, why?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Debra! I have to admit this sounds a bit like a homework problem to me, and it may have been down-voted for that reason. Have you tried yourself to come up with an answer for this? If so, what have you come up with and why? We're here to help on things you're stuck with, but we need to know what the specific problem is that you're having. Why are you having difficulty deciding whether this is a fragment or not?

Comment: It's just a noun phrase, with no verb, so it's not a "standard" sentence. This is GR.

Comment: Normally sentence consist of at least one noun phrase subject, and one predicate, normally a verb. In a pinch, the noun phrase can omitted. But without some predicate you don't have a sentence. A noun phrase like the one you quote is probably functioning as the subject or object in the previous discourse, like _They're all crap. All of them, that is, but Storm,_ or possibly _I love those bands. All of them, that is, but Storm._ What's happened is that Conjunction Reduction has applied across what are sposta be written sentences. Happens all the time; think nothing of it.

Comment: I really wish the title of this question was just, "Sentence fragment?"

Answer (score 1):

It is not a proper sentence, for the simple reason that it is missing a predicate. A good rule of thumb is that if the sentence doesn't have a verb, it probably does not have a predicate. The above sentence definitely has no verb.

In informal writing, this sentence would probably be fine, if the surrounding context provides an obvious predicate. For example, the context could be:

*"All the superheroes were at the meeting place. All of them but Storm."* (Apparently Storm is a superheroine.)

The first sentence above implies that the predicate is *"were at the meeting place"*.

That means the second sentence actually is saying:

*"All **[the superheroes]** but Storm **were at the meeting place.**"*

Answer (score 0):

I understand "sentence fragment" as meaning that it is not a complete sentence.
If I transform the sentence a bit I get: All of them, except Storm.
"All of them" is not a complete sentence.

The question might have been: How many have come? The shortest answer would be:
All of them/ All of them except Storm.

In normal language one would not answer with a complete sentence as "All of them have come." -  Now this is a complete sentence with a subject (all of them) and a predicate or verbal part (have come). But in everyday language answers are given in the shortest form and not in complete sentences. So you really have a fragment of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, anything other than a true sentence (minimum subject + predicate) appearing in print was considered unacceptable (or worse).

The fact that most people are quite happy to respond to questions, or tack on additional information to a previous sentence, with strings like

> "Yes."
>
> "Please."
>
> "Plee-eeze!"
>
> "A nice juicy one."
>
> "In a minute"
>
> "The one with the waggly tail."

has shown most people that the traditional 'rule' was too prescriptive. The underlying rationale was that utterances / written strings should make sense: if you utter or write any of the above examples without suitable context, you'll get some strange looks. But in the right context, they're fine, often more suitable than complete sentences.

I'd call the shortest examples (Yes, No, Here, Please!, Why? ...) sentence substitutes, and the longer ones, where a person coming in as you were speaking could make a good guess at what you were talking about, sentence fragments.

> All of them, that is, but Storm.

is a sentence fragment. Note that it is given the capital and the stop given to true sentences.